# LED Strips input supply directional

Tags: led-strip

I'm newbie and would like to know about LED strips.

[image]

In this schematic can I use the flow from Diagram B? I understand that Diagram A is the correct +12V Input supply and I can measure the end of the led with the same voltage and can also continue to link another led strip. With Diagram B to supply +12v supply it will still turn ON the LED but the end of the LED is 0v. I hope I'm making any sense. I already installed the LED strip underwater with Diagram B. I want to know will my mistake break my PSU and can cause issue on both LED and PSU? although its working.

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you mean by power directional. Power directional means whether or not you can swap the connection for 12V and 0V pins and reverse the flow of current through the diodes. You can't. But are you thinking of power being supplied through the strip from the +12V on one end to the +12V on the other end ? That should not be directional. But there are limits to what load you can put on the other end, if you exceed it you may create a fire hazard.

Comment: Thank you for correcting what I mean. Your right, that's what I meant. I supply one end of the led strip +12v instead of the other end. What I experienced is a supplied +12v where I can read the label where to can cut the length. When I cut my preferred length It didn't cross my mind if it matters which end the supply should I connect as long as the polarity is correct. I accidentally supply 12v on the other end. The LED strip light up but no output supply. And this is bad right? The LED is turned on. Thank you!

Comment: "*The LED strip light up but no output supply.*" What does this mean?

Comment: Yes you can use 'Diagram B' same as 'Diagram A'. If you have already installed the strip underwater you should investigate to see if you have some short circuit or low impedance path (e.g. due to the water) or open circuit (corroded leads, etc).

Answer (score 5):

[image]

*Figure 1. A typical LED strip.*

[image]

*Figure 2. The typical power-rail and three series LEDs arrangement. Source: [LEDnique](http://lednique.com/technology-basics/flexible-led-strip-light/).*

The required current limiting resistance can be made of one or two series resistors.

It should be clear from the schematic that if the strip is cut as shown in Figure 1 that the lone LED on the left and the two orphans on the right will have lost their connection to the supply rails. The three sets of three in the centre will light as expected but the outer ones will not. This is the reason for the scissor symbols.

---

> I understand that Diagram A is the correct +12V Input supply and I can measure the end of the led with the same voltage ... but the end of the LED [B] is 0 V.

The important thing is that there is 12 V between the rails at both ends.

> I already installed the LED strip underwater with Diagram B. I want to know will my mistake break my PSU and can cause issue on both LED and PSU?

Provided they are insulated against water ingress there will be no problem. You can feed those strips from either end.

Comment: @marlon: See the update.